# Bug in MVC2 means I need to compile the source, but nothing works with the compiled assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, assembly-resolution

There seems to be an issue around generating IDs with indexers within the MVC Framework (as detailed here http://aspnet.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=5495).

To fix this, I've downloaded the source, modified it and tried using it - but due to the lack of snk file for signing in the source download, everything I try is resulting in referencing hell.

Is there a way I can fix this issue without re-compiling the source, or get my modified copy to work?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Maybe it can be addressed from a different angle.

Comment: As the link describes, the IDs generated when using an IList are incorrect, meaning post information doesn't get correctly bound to the models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[These steps work for me](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/02/03/using-the-aspnet-mvc-source-code-to-debug-your-app/).